# Sorting facts in Prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog

How can I sort facts on its variable Like

> Student(5).
>   Student(3).
>   Student(2).
>   Student(3).
>   Student(6).

I want to make function to make them appear

> Student(2).
>   Student(3).
>   Student(3).
>   Student(5).
>   Student(6).

Answer (score 1):

I would first collect all these facts to a list using findall (example: [How to create a list from facts in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615150/how-to-create-a-list-from-facts-in-prolog)) , and then sort this list (example: [Sorting a list in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429479/sorting-a-list-in-prolog) , or just use the built-in sort/2 predicate ).

(Sent from my phone)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, they are not facts in proper Prolog, you need to write them with small letters:

```
student(5).
student(3).
% etc
```

Then, several things you can do:

```
?- findall(S, student(S), Students), msort(Students, Sorted).
```

(as suggested in the other answer)

If you want to have them actually sorted in the database, and are not afraid to change the database at run-time, you can then remove all `student/1` from the database with `abolish/1` and re-insert the sorted facts:

```
reorder_students :-
    findall(S, student(S), Students),
    msort(Students, Sorted), % do not remove duplicates
    abolish(student/1),
    forall(
        member(M, Sorted),
        assertz(student(M))
    ).
```

It is not a very good idea to do this repeatedly! If you have a regularly changing database of students you might consider not putting them in the database, but instead using for example an association list as in [library(assoc)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc)

Comment: Your first query will return L=[3,5]. How about getting L=[student(3),student(5)] because I think OP is looking for this. Also can we use setof/3?

Comment: @ssBarBee Your suggestion is confusing a list of facts in the database with a list of terms. It is a matter of taste I guess. You can't use `setof/3` if you follow the exact question, as it will remove duplicates. Or am I misunderstanding your comment somehow?